# how to adjust subtotal columns in pandas using grouby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtotal

I'm working on exporting data frames to Excel using dataframe join.

However, after Join dataframe,
when calculating subtotal using groupby, the figure below is executed.

There's a "Subtotal" word in the index column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY3Zz.png)

Is there any way to move it into the code column and sort the indexes?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxNKC.png)

here codes :

```
    def subtotal(df__, str):

        container = []


        for key, group in df__.groupby(['key']):
            group.loc['subtotal'] = group[['quantity', 'quantity2', 'quantity3']].sum()
            container.append(group)


        df_subtotal = pd.concat(container)
        df_subtotal.loc['GrandTotal'] = df__[['quantity', 'quantity2', 'quantity3']].sum()

        print(df_subtotal)
        return (df_subtotal.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.where()` to fill NaN in `code` column with value in `df.index`. Then assign a new index array to `df.index`.

```py
import numpy as np

df['code']  = np.where(df['code'].isna(), df.index, df['code'])
df.index = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
```

```
print(df)

          code  key    product  quntity1  quntity2   quntity3
1      cs01767    a    apple-a        10          0      10.0
2     Subtotal  NaN        NaN        10          0      10.0
3       cs0000    b  bannana-a        50         10      40.0
4       cs0000    b  bannana-b         0          0       0.0
5       cs0000    b  bannana-c         0          0       0.0
6       cs0000    b  bannana-d        80         20      60.0
7       cs0000    b  bannana-e         0          0       0.0
8      cs01048    b  bannana-f         0          0       NaN
9      cs01048    b  bannana-g         0          0       0.0
10    Subtotal  NaN        NaN       130         30     100.0
11     cs99999    c    melon-a        50         10      40.0
12     cs99999    c    melon-b        20         20       0.0
13     cs01188    c    melon-c        10          0      10.0
14    Subtotal  NaN        NaN        80         30      50.0
15  GrandTotal  NaN        NaN       220         60     160.0
```